# apache camel jetty websocket java.net.BindException

Tags: java, spring, websocket, apache-camel

I try to connect a websocket with [Apache Camel Jetty Websocket Component](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/websocket-component.html)
The Websocket's url is : `wss://echo.websocket.org`

I'am stuck with this error :

```
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: MultiException[java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to echo.websocket.org/174.129.224.73:443, java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to echo.websocket.org/174.129.224.73:443]
```

I havent really understand how he choose between ws and wss , i Try to put a self signed sslContextParameters/

Here si my code :

```
@Configuration
public class EipConfiguration extends RouteBuilder {


        @Override
        public void configure() {
            CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();

            String server = "echo.websocket.org";
            int port = 443;

            String uri = "websocket://"+server+":"+port+"/?sslContextParameters=#sslContextParameters";
        from(uri)
                .log(">>> Message received from WebSocket Client : ${body}");
    }

    @Bean(name = "sslContextParameters")
    public SSLContextParameters sslContextParameters() throws Exception {
        TrustManagersParameters trustManagersParameters = new TrustManagersParameters();
        X509ExtendedTrustManager extendedTrustManager = new InsecureX509TrustManager();
        trustManagersParameters.setTrustManager(extendedTrustManager);

        SSLContextParameters sslContextParameters = new SSLContextParameters();
        sslContextParameters.setTrustManagers(trustManagersParameters);

        return sslContextParameters;
    }

}
```

InsecureX509TrustManager

```
public class InsecureX509TrustManager extends X509ExtendedTrustManager {
    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s, Socket socket) throws CertificateException {
        //Do nothing

    }

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s, Socket socket) throws CertificateException {
        //Do nothing

    }

    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s, SSLEngine sslEngine) throws CertificateException {
        //Do nothing

    }

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s, SSLEngine sslEngine) throws CertificateException {
        //Do nothing

    }

    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws CertificateException {
        //Do nothing

    }

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws CertificateException {
        //Do nothing

    }

    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return new X509Certificate[0];
    }





    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jetty WebSocket Component (and Atmosphere WebSocket component) is intended to expose new WebSocket server. If you need to connect as client to remote WebSocket server, you should use [AHC Websocket component](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/ahc-ws-component.html)

> The AHC-WS component provides Websocket based endpoints for a client communicating with external servers over Websocket (as a client opening a websocket connection to an external server).